# forEach function for multiple sheets in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to run a script that will copy info from multiple different sheets to a different file. I am having issues with the  `forEach` function. The error I am getting is:

Error
ReferenceError: sheets is not defined
copy    @ Code.gs:9
copyInfo    @ Code.gs:4

```
function copyInfo() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  sheets.forEach(copy)
}


function copy() {
      var sheetName = sheets.getActiveSheet.getName();
      if(sheetName.includes("*"))
        var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var sheetName=copySheet.getName();
        var pasteSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NXmdq6yCKC6oiDAQNXcovj85697__rCeVJiIT_ou_gI");

  //Create new sheet if one doesn't exist
  var newSheet = pasteSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);   
  
  if (newSheet != null) 
    pasteSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
    newSheet = pasteSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    newSheet.setName(sheetName);

  //Copy and paste data
  
  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  newSheet.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange("B2:B");
  var values = source.getValues();
  // get destination range
  var destination = newSheet.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length);
   // copy values to destination range
  destination.setValues(values);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a function to use with forEach, that function needs to accept an individual item as a parameter.  In this case, each "sheet" from SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets() will be passed as the first parameter into your copy function - but the copy function doesn't accept any params as is.

```
function copy(sheet) {
      var sheetName = sheet.getName();
      if(sheetName.includes("*"))
      ...
}
```

Comment: I understand the mistake I made, but I fixed it and I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined"

Comment: Well...I figured it out. It was just syntax of course. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

#### This might work

```
function copyInfo() {
  const dontcopy = ["Sh1","Sh2",...];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  sheets.filter(sh => !~dontcopy.indexOf(sh.getName()).forEach(s => {
    s.activate();
    copy();
  });
}
```

Comment: There are certain sheets that cannot get copied, and I only need selected columns from the sheets I am copying. Thank you for your reply

Comment: So you can use filter to filter them out